# Need Javascript for Specific Response in Contact Form (text must equal "yes")

Tags: javascript, contact-form, verification

I currently have a contact form that requires a user to type 'yes' to an agreement. I have knowledge of HTML and CSS, but do not know the possible Javascript code to require the user to enter 'yes' in the text box and to prevent the message from going through if they were to enter 'no' or any other response other than 'yes'. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: So did you try anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pattern attribute and the form will take care of the validation

```html
<form>
  <label for="confirm">Type yes</label>
  <input type="text" id="confirm" name="confirm" placeholder="yes" pattern="^yes$" required>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: +1 - Like this more than my answer, might want to do more than just this, but this is definitely the cleanest way to meet OP criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Simple JavaScript code will look something like
Will run when user tries to submit form

```
document.getElementByTagName("form").addEventListener("submit", function(event){
    //get your input by id:
    let input_validate = document.getElementById("your input id");
    if(input_validate.value.toUpperCase() !== "YES"){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('Please write yes in the input');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to give you what you're looking for without more context/your HTML and how you want to handle an input you don't want (error message, prevent form submit, redirect to new page, all of the above). This could go in a function called onchange of the input, or within a function called during form submit.

```
var response = document.getElementById('[your_inputs_id]').value;
if(response == "yes"){
    //do things, or submit, or do nothing
    return true;
}
else{
   //display error message, don't submit, etc.
   return false;
}
```